# Nginx - multiple vhost that require access to shared function

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

i have some php application under 1 docroot as below :

```
/data/app/
|-- antispam.php
|-- api
|   `-- functions.php
|-- images
|-- messaging
|-- parents
|   `-- index.php
`-- students
    `-- index.php
```

i want to create some vhost from above directory such that the docroot become :

```
/data/app/parents : parents.example.com 
/data/app/students : students.example.com
```

those vhost will need access to some shared function from /data/app (antispam.php , api/functions.php, messaging/ & images/)

some snippet from my nginx config :
parents.example.com

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  parents.example.com;
        root   /data/app/parents;
        index index.php ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log combined;
        location ~ ^/api { root /data/app/; }
        location ~ ^/images { root /data/app/; }
        location ~ ^/antispam.php {  alias /data/app/antispam.php ; 
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

above configuration working as long as I defined the location and the docroot (/data/app) have a valid directory. the problem is if I have 100 directories (contain PHP script) in /data/app that required by a vhost, should I define each of them in Nginx server block? I wondered that if none defined in location block, it will search in /data/app/ first before committing 404, something like try_files maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use symbolic links on the filesystem so that `/data/app/parents/antispam.php` is a symbolic link pointing to `../antispam.php`. You can perform the same with subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in a server_name directive and then reuse them in other directives, including the root directive.

So you should be able to define infinite subdomains using a single block, something like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  ~(?<subdomain>^.*?)\.?example\.com;
        root   /data/app/$subdomain;
        index index.php;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/$subdomain.example.com.log combined;

        location /api/ {
            root /data/app;
        }

        location /images/ {
            root /data/app;
        }
        location ~ \/antispam.php$ { 
            alias /data/app/antispam.php ; 
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Comment: uhm, i think i gave uncomplete question, what if parents.example.com will need access to 
/data/app/api2
/data/app/image2

Comment: Drop the slash on `location /api/` and `location /images/` and then apixxxx and imagesxxxx will also match, but I thought the point was so you could just have single images and api directories that every subdomain was served identical content from?

Comment: oh yes, and also 100 other directory that name is not api* and images*, like another sub-application. if it was too complex, i think i will just create special index.php for each subdomain.

Comment: Kind of defeats the object of php if you are just going to create all the pages yourself

Comment: yeah, kind of "quick fix" :D meanwhile i still open for better solution

Comment: Change your project directory structure, have 2 directories in root dir, 1 called static and 1 called domains or whatever. Then serve all images, js, css etc from the static dir and create subdirs in the domains dir for each subdomains unique files